# Is Gunicorn alone is enough to host a Flask application/ Is it must to configure Gunicorn

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, gunicorn, wsgi, flask-restful

I have many flask application running as independent module. (No web pages is serving here, no CSS, or any script file). It's purely Rest based Web services which do some processing and return the response.

I would like to take these flask application to the production grade. Thus, I need to change the internal flask server with some other production grade server. Over the Internet, I found that we should go with the some WSGI server (GUnicorn with NGINX as proxy server). As we don't have any static web pages to serve here, I'm confused whether I should configure NGINX or Gunicorn alone with Async worker is enough to handle the load on production.

Note: We have huge load over the production as it will processing over 100k images.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Gunicorn with Nginx. Gunicorn is python WSGI server.

Quoting from Gunicorn website: *It is best to use Gunicorn behind an HTTP proxy server. We strongly advise you to use nginx.*
[reference](https://gunicorn.org/#deployment)

Answer (score 0):

I also found that unicorn is better alternative to Gunicorn. [Reference](https://stackshare.io/stackups/gunicorn-vs-uvicorn#:%7E:text=Uvicorn%3A%20The%20lightning%2Dfast%20ASGI%20server.&text=Uvicorn%20and%20Gunicorn%20belong%20to,stars%20and%20214%20GitHub%20forks.)